Using DevCheck app to check File-System of External-Storage
The DevCheck app shows that an SD-card of mine is formatted as sdfat, which tells me that it's formatted as some sort of FAT-system. I have been searching online for some way to just see exactly which format an External-Storage device has—as can very easily be done with Windows, Mac or iOS otherwise—but all methods suggested by the internet have either been made redundant by time or else are very complicated and too difficult for someone unfamiliar with in-depth usage of Android; and besides, even then it looks like you can't get beyond a vague 'Driver' categorisation of a given File-System, so it looks like it's actually impossible to do this with Android.
Having said that, am I right to think that it doesn't really matter? because after-all Android only accepts External-Storage devices formatted as FAT and exFAT anyway. So, if the device can't be read by Android, then it is neither FAT nor exFAT, in which-case some other OS could read it; and if it does read it, then it is either FAT or exFAT.

Even if "Android" (thus AOSP) only accepts FAT and exFAT formatted media your actual device may behave different if your device manufacturer has modified the Android system.

When I said "Android only excepts" those File-Systems I guess I meant my particular device according to its manual, so I just assumed that that was true for all Android devices also.

How do I find what type of file system is of an attached USB or SD card?
